# Is there a way to compose class mixins in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mixins, typescript-generics

I have a hierarchy of class mixins that work in plain JavaScript.

```
const
  AsFoo = ( superclass ) => class extends superclass {
    get foo(){ return true; }
  },

  AsFooBar = ( superclass ) => class extends AsFoo( superclass ){
    get bar(){ return true; }
  },

  FooBar = AsFooBar( Object ),
  fb = new FooBar();

console.log( fb.foo, fb.bar );
// true, true
```

However when I translate them to TypeScript, I get an error with `AsFoo( superclass )`.

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new ( ...args: any[] ) => T;

interface Foo {
    foo: boolean;
}

interface FooBar extends Foo {
    bar: boolean;
}

const
  AsFoo = <T extends Constructor>( superclass: T ): Constructor<Foo> & T => class extends superclass implements Foo {
    get foo(){ return true; }
  },
  AsFooBar = <T extends Constructor>( superclass: T ): Constructor<FooBar> & T => class extends AsFoo<T>( superclass ) implements FooBar {
    get bar(){ return true; }
  };

// Type 'Constructor<Foo> & T' is not a constructor function type. ts(2507)
```

Is there something I can do to make TypeScript work with this pattern? I'd rather not just `// @ts-ignore: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯` it.

I am currently using TypeScript 3.2.4.

Comment: Related https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4890

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743

Comment: Ultimately the problem is that typescript in `AsFooBar` won't like that you are extending from a generic type parameter. Mixins are a special exception to this rule and they are only allowed in a specific scenario. I would go with something like the answer below..

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, thanks for the links. I'll check them out.

Answer (score 3):

```
export type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
/* turns A | B | C into A & B & C */
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void)
    ? I
    : never;
/* merges constructor types - self explanitory */
export type MergeConstructorTypes<T extends Array<Constructor<any>>> = UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<T[number]>>;

export function Mixin<T extends Array<Constructor<any>>>(constructors: T): Constructor<MergeConstructorTypes<T>> {
    const cls = class {
        state = {};

        constructor() {
            constructors.forEach((c: any) => {
                const oldState = this.state;
                c.apply(this);
                this.state = Object.assign({}, this.state, oldState);
            });
        }
    };
    constructors.forEach((c: any) => {
        Object.assign(cls.prototype, c.prototype);
    });
    return cls as any;
}
```

this is an implementation i was playing around with awhile back, it also merges the states of each class but feel free to alter that part to suit your needs.

The usage is as follows...

```
class A {
    getName() {
        return "hello"
    }
}


class B {
    getClassBName() {
        return "class B name"
    }
}

class CombineAB extends Mixin([A, B]) {
    testMethod() {
        this.getClassBName //is here
        this.getName // is here
    }
}
```