# Typescript mixin function with generic type from main class

Tags: typescript, generics, mixins

I have the following code

```
// Types found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55468194
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
/* turns A | B | C into A & B & C */
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ( k: infer I ) => void ? I : never;
/* merges constructor types - self explanitory */
type MergeConstructorTypes<T extends Array<Constructor<any>>> = UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<T[number]>>;

var Mixin = function <T extends Constructor[]>(
  ...mixins: T
): Constructor<MergeConstructorTypes<T>> {
  const MixinSuperClass: Constructor<MergeConstructorTypes<T>> = class {
  } as Constructor<MergeConstructorTypes<T>>;
  return MixinSuperClass;
};

type all = "all1" | "all2";

class ClassA<T extends string = all | "a1" | "a2"> {
  hopa(p: T | all) {
    return 'a' + p;
  }
}

class ClassB {
  hopb(p: all) {
    return 'b' + p;
  }
}

class ClassOK extends Mixin(ClassA<"aa">, ClassB) { }
const c = new ClassOK;
c.hopa("aa"); // the "aa" value has been autocompleted

class ClassKO<T extends string = ""> extends Mixin(ClassA<T>, ClassB) { } // Just notice that Mixin is not limited to only 2 args
class ClassFinal extends ClassKO<"aaa"> {}
const d = new ClassKO<"a" | "b">;
d.hopa("aa"); // here there was no autocomplete while I would like to have "aa"
const de = new ClassFinal;
de.hopa("aaa"); // here there was no autocomplete while I would like to have "aaa"
```

`Mixin` is a function that works well to give here the typing for `ClassOk`. In order to make it the shortest I can I remove the functional parts so now the code can not be ran. The important thing I looking for is a way that `de.hopa("` autocomplete the value `"aaa"`, based on `ClassFinal extends ClassKO<"aaa">`.
My main difficulty is the Mixin function definition with generic types…

Here is a complete [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE8AcFMGdQDMD2BXAdgE1CjoALAFyOngC4R4iBDAYwGsUA3WAJyQBsUB3AOjooAtsBrAArOIAsANgAcARgCcUgFBEYsUAGE81NmjpEUbADzhQAXlABvAL4A+K6AyweoABR9vNNgHMKUBoMSABtAF0ASisncABuVWAAKlAiNDYMRABBUAAfUAAhPJ1QAEsMY1AcgDJC0FrtUCTgdU1QAFUMUrxwFABJCvZ4WCNujFN2p2sPdtBYAA8iWGxEYMhQAH5PBnIO6MsnZhRSnF3XVjZohaWVz1AdsowkdlA+0H3D45wtt7PYC4SyVAQnYfgQoEEmSIBiMJlSmkQAFpQMNOEg5vNoJxgqVjGx1s1WnBQABZUGwXRQmF4qBweDmDE3LDZNhsGiQUyU-SGPGmNYOAXOTpjXoDJZsYajPCmAbUYJ0WC02DmUIYNBCABG7HCAoSqmYvlJpXm5WcSEwUvwDOuy2ZOj00J5JgiDg8qlAoG8fCExvKgXAqkiuy5jthZjJ-gpDupJiV9PAgps7ohDqNJowAGU0HA2NpsfBAiGY+HyUWnWw4+ZBdY6PnEEmPXYgogy2HTBGwa2aQiqw4Eh62LA0hk0+Uszm8zQCwk7HqNMSaJxOM4AESLzgKFfFNdLgBMK71tanLbrWWti1tiH05T8znX25om4f+6cDcIKGgNA80F2Fny6+iN8ByHdJ8AAchoMDQAAalAaB+1AOxVCQ1QjwLHQ6yKN8CA-DVv12ADbGTYDh3AjUoNg+DkyQlC0JPY8AHkAGlGUvUcMA8ScCzPNcaBXBwABoMOPApAMQ1DUzoZxXHcLj4GYhI6D4HDPw8XiV0iOJQBAVICC0dTQANTg0C0Agp1ALVliCNBjEEIQsSHWAsFUVC62EgsmIY88mSvaEb1XfjWNuElfQ4uSzwTIS5NE2xEO0sAACk0GoFwUCIUoFV0mgiHYspEAwNLQE4UofSWHBKjwTh1l3IJ-HgVzj3c+AADFykXIK7TkzzTF4vjXyQyEUpwawZKa7q1y3fIVw1fiEiwZSPy-dTNPiwh2C0Ig9MHUAeHMgrrNs4QHKWHaCFKTgtDeHh0E4HBioYDaUEIGhWFAdSJKhUAsC0Ea3Ca1qMEXObYAW1Teo0rSdK2jboZ2vanpoGyUDs46tB4M6LteHabru0oHtSJ6zNe8GgA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  I'm not inclined to try to guess what `Whatever` might look like, since I might well get it wrong enough to make a difference in the answer.

Comment: Thank @jcalz I edited my question with a link to the complete code I have done.

Comment: In order for code to be a [mre] it should be in the text of the question as plaintext, not just available at a link (see the italicized "*in the question itself*" part of the relevant doc).  Please [edit] to do that.  Also, the "complete code" there is likely to be complete but quite unlikely to be *minimal*.  Could you provide a toy implementation that demonstrates the same issue?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this that keeps `Mixin` as a *variadic* function.  Maybe you could support up to some fixed number of inputs that preserves generics and then variadic which delete them?  [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mAgQZw) is how supporting just two ctor inputs might look.  If that's promising I can expand on it and/or write up an answer.  Otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: [example supporting generics for up to 4 inputs and then not for more than that](https://tsplay.dev/mpAL7W)

Comment: Oh thank you for your fast comment ! I found that solution already, and was looking for a way to fix it for variadic Mixin function.
If there is no solution I will accept that final solution :-) Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the example of 4 ! That's more than enough I guess !! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately TypeScript lacks true support for higher order [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types, also known as "higher kinded types", as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) and other GitHub issues.  So in general this is technically impossible.  Still:

There is some [limited support for propagating generics from generic constructors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-constructors), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#31116](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31116), but it only works in very specific circumstances.  You can't use it to make `Mixin` a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), and you specifically need to make your function generic in both the constructor arguments and its return type.  It does give us a handle we can use to try to get something like the behavior you're looking for, though.

One approach you can take is to define `Mixin` to be an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) where you hardcode call signatures for some small number of inputs (up to four, say) that will have their generic propagated as desired, and then fall back to the variadic version which works for more inputs but does not propagate generics.

Like this, maybe:

```
type C<A extends any[], R> = abstract new (...args: A) => R

declare const Mixin: {
  // explicitly support generics for 1, 2, 3, or 4 inputs
  <A1 extends any[], R1>(
    ctor1: C<A1, R1>
  ): new (...args: any) => R1
  <A1 extends any[], R1, A2 extends any[], R2>(
    ctor1: C<A1, R1>, ctor2: C<A2, R2>
  ): new (...args: any) => R1 & R2
  <A1 extends any[], R1, A2 extends any[], R2, A3 extends any[], R3>(
    ctor1: C<A1, R1>, ctor2: C<A2, R2>, ctor3: C<A3, R3>
  ): new (...args: any) => R1 & R2 & R3
  <A1 extends any[], R1, A2 extends any[], R2, 
   A3 extends any[], R3, A4 extends any[], R4>(
    ctor1: C<A1, R1>, ctor2: C<A2, R2>, ctor3: C<A3, R3>, ctor4: C<A4, R4>
  ): new (...args: any) => R1 & R2 & R3 & R4
  
  // fall back to variadic 
  <R extends any[]>(
    ...ctors: { [I in keyof R]: new (...args: any) => R[I] }
  ): new (...args: any) => 
    { [I in keyof R]: (x: R[I]) => void }[number] extends (
      x: infer I) => void ? I : never;
}
```

It's not pretty, but it works:

```
class Foo<T extends string> {
  constructor(public t: T) {}
}
class Bar<U extends number, V extends boolean> {
  constructor(public u: U, public v: V) {}
}

const Mixed = Mixin(Foo, Bar);
// const Mixed: new <T extends string, U extends number, V extends boolean>(
//  ...args: any) => Foo<T> & Bar<U, V>
```

And you can pass generics along by instantiating the result of `Mixin` (so you'd write `Mixin(Foo, Bar)<T, U, V>` and not `Mixin(Foo<T>, Bar<U, V>)`:

```
class GenMixed<
  T extends string, U extends number, V extends boolean
> extends Mixin(Foo, Bar)<T, U, V> { }
```

So as long as you need only up to some fixed number of inputs, you're fine:

```
const M1 = Mixin(Foo);
// const M1: new <T extends string>(...args: any) => Foo<T>
const M2 = Mixin(Foo, Foo);
// const M2: new <T extends string, T1 extends string>(
//  ...args: any) => Foo<T> & Foo<T1>
const M3 = Mixin(Foo, Foo, Foo);
// const M3: new <T extends string, T1 extends string, T2 extends string>(
//  ...args: any) => Foo<T> & Foo<T1> & Foo<T2>
const M4 = Mixin(Foo, Foo, Foo, Foo);
// const M4: new <T extends string, T1 extends string, T2 extends string, 
//   T3 extends string>(
//   ...args: any) => Foo<T> & Foo<T1> & Foo<T2> & Foo<T3>
```

Just keep in mind that if you exceed it, the behavior falls back to the non-generic version:

```
const M5 = Mixin(Foo, Foo, Foo, Foo, Foo);
// const M5: new (...args: any) => Foo<string>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgPAQShAHsCA7AJgZygQwxAG0BdAGigCUA+KAXgICMdgAnfAY2CgwgHcoACgB0Y-GwDmOAFxQEASgZ0qAKFVYInADYTonAPYZWUALIBLFOYxyA3qqhQA9E+Qow2853PBtIKDgArmBgBmw8kpgQbF54AGZhUACMlABMlADMlIkALFDWYIHAOA5QiElu6Nh4hCQU1Ek0QqWO3GFJcvAIKQ00pQpyfIKi4lKyBERK9CpJpeWVmLgTdZRUPQipC9XLZKupTS1QbWwdsOWrjZTHqZ2I6dT7-YMCwmIiEtJytVMzUABkDzm3S2S1quwalA2IJqRHBVHuCAy0J29SoGQOjlawHat26FxoV2xbBuZw2ewJRyJGVxWWo6KevBeI3eYy+k2UDX+Dy5aKBFVQVVBsNR602AsWMJWD0hSPF2zBqNpCDycqFUqoOQxmOOpy6PTWFOuuPu8MNVJpq3RhLCOVxOVWmoZQ1eo0+yx+nIB8J5SK9OXUjhcUDi+G02igTC4AGsoNioAA3CTmfBYLxQOZUZEKrWON7Hca2KDEACS+QwUCjEBABji1FIz2Gbw+42+HKoJdIUAAvk6mU3We6OYWS2WK1Wa3W5EIUHJ28XSB74wZzFhu8QMIEALZMaKd1V4adyaxxaJQYuL5ergD8Z6gz3j0QA3Koe6odPgcHgAGIGAxwAAqyKsDEGCSHQ9itEYwGBMcQiFEwnicLGcj-kohY9j276flAABCEhwAAqsiG7btElAAGrIkwv7aBAhDgaUhjGOwMFEnBgQIWmgRyARlDwYhCZyORaHdi+6hMSYFgoBAq6MFJ1hCD+BiUHhbAKM+QYSTwUkyQ2ZSAfuATsNYkiUERhkkTubAUVRNF0RgBxBlA-Zuq20xQEpAF0ACqmERRfRvro2EAOKYDpWBwKUBloBKRkgaZUDmTF2yWWRUCUYZ1EGLRhCqHQhnyRgim-ipEgKABZn+VA6HiVB2kVHJlgKUp6mqJpdVmKczoAUBxmgU0Lktuy7mef+fRaWYmyNVYRVKZQLUaa4E2mCS3XRYKeDASZlD-vyyVLFt-XNE5g1siAHqjd5Hm-gBjRvh1phItNzUlddylva17XMWY1KMoIPWGYdCW7b18U7WK+2bX1YHHa4zmukN50cpdXKjY0qM3f+jzLXkz2za9c1vfNv6fUtD22n9+mg9tUAg4D0Pg9ToGUG1cO07KkNxSZjls6dg4jZjV1o0LmP7Bjf7-vSy0AKwMGYTX4+9hPKwTJOLUcD3S3pzLNmdF03UDfRAA)