# Make mixin with generic type - phase 2

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mixins

I would like to define generic type for my mixin method that uses "extending class creating functions". But I am unable to define the good syntax in order to do it.

I took the implementation in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76585028/762461

Here is a short and simple example :

```js
// The type for the so called "extending class creating functions"
type Mixable<A extends any[], R> = (
  ctor: new (...args: any[]) => any
) => abstract new (...args: A) => R;

type MixinFunction = {
  <A1 extends any[], R1>(ctor1: Mixable<A1, R1>): new (...args: any) => R1;
  <A1 extends any[], R1, A2 extends any[], R2>
  (ctor1: Mixable<A1, R1>, ctor2: Mixable<A2, R2>): new (...args: any) => R1 & R2;
}

const Mixin: MixinFunction = ((_a: Mixable<any[], any>) => {
  // this content is only for the example
  return class {} as (new (...args: any[]) => any);
});

const Base = (superclass: Newable) => class _Base extends superclass {
  foo():number {
    return 1;
  }
};

const Base2 = <T>(superclass: Newable) => class _Base2 extends superclass {
  bar():T {
    return 1 as T;
  }
};

// class Derived<T> extends Mixin(Base, Base2<T>) doesn't work because of ts(2562)
class Derived<T> extends Mixin(Base, Base2) {
}

class DerivedString extends Derived<string> {}

(new Derived()).foo();          // infered as "number"
(new DerivedString()).bar();    // I would like to infer the return type here as "string"
```

Comment: This is beyond TS's current abilities; it lacks various features like higher kinded types [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)) and base class expressions reference type parameters [ms/TS#55972](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55972)). If you need this you'll need to work around it, maybe write out your types manually and use type assertions each time, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1L3yW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz this is what I was afraid of… Thank you for your proposal. As I need this mixin works in typescript AND to convert it through a special ts->js transpiler (the js I need has many language limitations) I'm looking for a solution that concentrate the mixin part in the fewest instructions I can (the function called in the extends was perfect) and the final js is stripped of all the types (and largely transformed as well). So you're solution seem ok :-) I'll try to find a way that is convenient to me based on your proposal. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately TypeScript lacks features necessary for you to write this sort of composed [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html).  The support for [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) only works in very specific circumstances, and using `Base2` (a generic function that returns a nongeneric class) as a `Mixable` (a generic *type* that returns a nongeneric function that returns a nongeneric class) isn't one of those circumstances.

To begin to support this sort of thing TypeScript would probably need, at the minimum, a loosening of the restriction of accessing type parameters in base class expressions as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#55972](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55972). But in general TypeScript can't really express the sort of higher-kinded types that represent the intended operation of `Mixin` when applied to generic inputs.  There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) for that, although again, it's not clear that an implementation for that would automatically fix your issue.

For now, this is just beyond TypeScript's abilities.

---

Instead of trying to get TypeScript to do what it can't, the best I can imagine doing is to figure out what type you expect `Mixin(Base, Base2<T>)` to produce, and then just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the result is of that type.  It's not great, but it's at least possible:

```
const Mixed = Mixin(Base, Base2) as new <T>(...args: any) =>
    InstanceType<ReturnType<typeof Base>> &
    InstanceType<ReturnType<typeof Base2<T>>>;
class Derived<T> extends Mixed<T> { }

class DerivedString extends Derived<string> { }
(new Derived()).foo(); // number
(new DerivedString()).bar(); // string
```

That's complicated, mostly because `Base` and `Base2` have hidden away their actual classes inside the function body scope, so there's no existing name for their instance types.  I use [the `ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) and [the `InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) utility types to tease that out.  The generics are handled by making `Mixed` a generic class constructor (that's the `<T>` in `new <T>(...args: any) => ⋯`) and then using an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) to specify `T` as the type argument for `typeof Base2`.

But it works; `Mixed` is seen as a generic class so you're allowed to write `class Derived<T> extends Mixed<T> {}`, and thus `DerivedString` has a `string` return type for `bar()`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsFNQFwJ4AdYDMD2AneNQGd1QBjAQwBszoATUAImgA85oA7KgSxYHNiyS88xTNBJxOPVAFcWRMehZ5aAKEQpQAWXYMSAI0oAeAIKhGzNoJIsEAbQC6AGlAAlAHygAvKAAUS0H+JwWABcoCzQAO7eAHQxJJhceCGWNrYAlB5uyUrp7pk6eHCYJLKhEdGx8YmghjluTgDcSirIsJoMnABi0rLs8h6gAN6+-kYAjCZMrFQWVnaOTqMuXrJYoyFtugaGo-OLqSFhkV4xUXEJSVa1zqON-qBjE2bToMlz146GAEyPUzMp858XMM7n5loFMGsNFpNtAxrsXI4VphPutoXpYV8AS59qUjiczlVklcFqAAGTOT6NAC+zTUADkIjD+odvFdko0lER5AUoe0WKi+V0ZHIWP0vF4APokAUw-SvBwvKzYjKDYGgEA4diCLksMxwUBa0DyMgIUAYbBwXCMEgAWyQlDVwjgkkwoqIfAEg1AVJegi8LOOFXOipSbMu1NSHJ1PIAQvxYJ4vHhJChMO7+FUGeEYVd056JXG8LBTL98CnoGmPYIhncMOgvDiWJIbToK6qQf4nS7RTc1TSqVHufrC9Bvp59OB7Etk6m85nGejc1XQAX498S+Yy7PlzX-Do4g2QuB2x3QF3XaBxvwILd-P3Bwp9W1qP02pwvCPHCPPulryyJ0s+KVBcCC1GqACSj6WEQ0DgC0+hONAzqunBKD6Ko0DoKgoAji4bikhBUEyLB8GIchLCobCGFYTha4AXhjRzqAAAiFbsAAbtQAE-Juz5UNxAzek0TGsZgHHUAAyoU4g8c8onifxBRidwbiCTS-plPJnFUA2qRRHWDb1OqYBNi2FZKBpkRaZJ0ncLpUT7pghnGfgtlcEAA)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed, knowledge and not opinion based explanation.